# WPF: How to find out which element is determining the window size?

Tags: wpf

I have a complex WPF window that uses several controls laid out in grids, stackpanels, etc. At run time I find the size of my window far too wide.

Normally, for a small code base, I would have examined the Width, MinWidth, MaxWidth, and Column Widths for the entire layout but I am working on a huge codebase (these controls are spread across dozens of XAML files and for some I don't even own the source code).

I am looking for a tool using which I can perhaps hover(?) over a control and find out how it derived its size. Is there something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to require the window to "fit to it's content"? If you start to use fixed sizes in a complex layout you've already lost...

Comment: @PaulMichalik It would but I hate to use that option unless I have no choice. Ideally, controls and windows should be well designed to not overflow to egregious levels and well behaved enough to be sized as the window wants them to be (not the other way round). I have already debugged my problem and found the culprit element but given that I lost a lot of time I started looking for a tool.

Comment: Isn't Snoop good enough to analyse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). This is an excellent visual dissambler for wpf. It is like firebug for wpf.